# How to make bootstrap icons to be in the center of the buttons?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap icons. I have added a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/verilog15/c0br6en2/) you can ues. It shows an that the bootstrap icons are not in the same line as the text in the button.

How can I make it to be in the center of the same `a` tag so it won't look so awkward.

Comment: I think Nisar has answered the best solution and should be accepted by you so that other developers can also benefit from it :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this css:

```
.error-template {
  padding: 40px 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.error-actions {
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.error-actions .btn {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.error-actions a {
  display: flex;
  align-item: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.error-actions a i {
  margin-right: 10px;
  line-height: 1.3;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/XWjPWOR

Comment: Your solution is also a nice one but we have to use display:flex; on <a> tag. What Nisar has done is directly setting line-height:1.2 on the specific icons itself :) But Nice try from you also :) Regardig my Answer. It was the overkill and I deleted it !!! Best of luck to you both

Answer (score 0):

It's a `line-height` issue. And can be resolved over-riding the CSS for these icons here doing the below code.

```
.error-actions i[class^="bi-"]::before, .error-actions i[class*=" bi-"]::before {
  line-height:1.2 !important;
}
```

**FULL WORKING CODE:**

```css
.error-template {
    padding: 40px 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

.error-actions {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.error-actions i[class^="bi-"]::before, .error-actions i[class*=" bi-"]::before {
  line-height:1.2 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">



<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="error-template">
                <h1>
                    404</h1>
                <h2>
                     Oops! Page Not Found</h2>
                <div class="error-details">
                    Sorry, but the page you were trying to view does not exist.
                </div>
                <div class="error-actions">
                    <a href="/" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><i class="bi bi-house-door-fill"></i> Go to Homepage </a>
                    <a href="/" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg"><i class="bi bi-envelope-fill"></i> Contact Support </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thing your answer is short and precise ! However, this will change line-heights in all the application for all the bootstrap-icons :)  Let me edit your code to edit only the specified icons in the button :)